# Moving column down in CSV with bash

Tags: bash, sorting, csv

I have the following data set in a semi-colon-seperated CSV file:

```
"11-01-2017";"17:13";"X";"";...
"11-01-2017";"";"X";"17:32";...
"11-01-2017";"20:13";"Y";"";...
"11-01-2017";"";"Y";"20:25";...
```

How do I, in bash, move every entry in the second column 1 place down, resulting in:

```
"11-01-2017";"";"X";"";...
"11-01-2017";"17:13";"X";"17:32";...
"11-01-2017";"";"Y";"";...
"11-01-2017";"20:13";"Y";"20:25";...
```

It is in this case essential the double quotes remain around the entry.

Comment: Do you always have `""` in 2nd column of every even numbered record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use awk with a script like this:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN { FS = ";"
        OFS= FS
        prev2 ="\"\""
    }
    { tmp = $2; $2 = prev2; prev2 = tmp }

    1
```

Run it like this: `awk -f script.awk yourfile`.

- the first block setups input and output separator to `;`
- the second block sets the second column to the value of the previous line and stores the value from the current line
- the `1` in the last line is a shorthand for printing the current values

Comment: Nice answer. However, it seems your script deletes the double quotes on the first value to be moved. Here's my output: `"11-01-2017";;"X";"";...
"11-01-2017";"17:13";"X";"17:32";...
"11-01-2017";"";"Y";"";...`

Comment: @JamilSaid Thanks for the hint. I updated the answer.

Comment: Doesn't this answer assume that output requires `""` in first record?

Comment: @anubhava Yes it does. And the original value in the last line is dropped.